# what is the difference between "web services" and "web-based services"?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, web

I googled the difference between "web services" and "web-based services". 
I could find that "web services" use the SOAP,XML and HTTP and "web-based services" use the HTML and HTTP. 
But I couldn't find the exact answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Web-based services** are services which is given to you through a website. As a example, you go to a website and use a html elements there to get the sum of two numbers. That is a web-based service. In this case you use HTML to presentation part and HTTP to communication part.
**Web service** is a service that you can use by sending a request through a SOAP/JSON like communication technologies and receive a response(If there's any). As a example you send a soap message containing two numbers from your Java/C#/Android client app, and receive the sum of two numbers in a SOAP message.